# Storing the data using Parallel Programming

Tags: performance, memory-management, out-of-memory, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

The requirement is as follows:

We have a third party client from where we need to take the data and store in the database(ultimately).

The way client is sharing data to us is through the dll's having functions(the dll is built out of C++ code) and we need to call those functions with appropriate parameters and we get the result.

```
Declare Function wcmo_deal Lib "E:\IGB\System\Intex\vcmowrap\vcmowr64.dll" (
    ByRef WCMOarg_Handle As String,
    ByRef WCMOarg_User As String,
    ByRef WCMOarg_Options As String,
    ByRef WCMOarg_Deal As String,
    ByRef WCMOarg_DataOut As String,
    ByRef WCMOarg_ErrOut As String) _
     As Long

wcmo_deal(wcmo_deal_WCMOarg_Handle, WCMOarg_User, WCMOarg_Options, WCMOarg_Deal, WCMOarg_DataOut, WCMOarg_ErrOut)
```

Here WCMOarg_DataOut is the data we get and that needs to be stored.

Similar to the above method we have 10 more methods(so,total 11 methods) which pull the data and that data(string of around 500 KB to 1 MB each) is stored in the files using the below method :

```
File.WriteAllText(logPath & sDealName & ".txt", sDealName & " - " & WCMOarg_ErrOut & vbCrLf)
```

Now these method calls run for each *deal*. So for a single deal we get output in 11 different folders with the text file stored with the data received from the client.

There are 5000 deals totally for which we need to call these methods and the data gets stored in the files.

The way this functionality has been implemented is by using Parallel Programming with Master-Child relationship as follows:

```
Dim opts As New ParallelOptions
opts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount
Parallel.ForEach(dealList, opts, Sub(deal)
                                                 If Len(deal) > 0 Then
                                                     Dim dealPass As String = ""
                                                     Try
                                                         If dealPassDict.ContainsKey(deal.ToUpper) Then
                                                             dealPass = dealPassDict(deal.ToUpper)
                                                         End If
                                                         Dim p As New Process()
                                                         p.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\IGB_New\CMBS Intex Data Deal v2.0.exe"
                                                         p.StartInfo.Arguments = deal & "|" & keycode & "|" & dealPass & "|" & clArgs(1) & "|"
                                                         p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                                                         p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
                                                         p.Start()
                                                         p.WaitForExit()
                                                     Catch ex As Exception
                                                         exceptions.Enqueue(ex)                                                             
                                                     End Try
                                                 End If
                                             End Sub)
```

where **CMBS Intex Data Deal v2.0.exe** is the child code which will execute 5000 times as deallist contains 5000 deals.

The CMBS Intex Data Deal v2.0.exe code contains the code of calling the dlls and storing the data in the files mentioned above.

Issues faced :

1. The code was run keeping the Master and Child code in one single place but we get out of memory exception after 3000 deals.[for 32 GB RAM,Processor Count =16]
2. The above code(Master-Child) is also taking up a lot of memory, it runs fine upto 4800 deals in one hour(the memory usage gradually reaches 100% at around 4800 deals) and then for the remaining 200 deals it takes close to 1 hour(so , totally 2 hours).[for 32 GB RAM,Processor Count =16]
   The reason Master child was tried was on the assumption that GC will take care of the Memory disposal of all the objects in the Child.

After the data is stored in text files, a perl script runs and loads the data into the database.

Approach tried:

Instead of keeping the data in text files and then storing into the database, I tried storing the data into the DB directly without putting them in the files (assuming I/O operations consume a lot of memory),but this too didnt work as the DB crashed/Hangs everytime.

Note:

1. All the handles related to the DLL is properly being closed.
2. The call to the DLL's method consume a lot of memory,but nothing can be done to reduce it as it cant be controlled by us.
3. The reason to use Parallel approach is if we go with sequential approach, it would take many hours to fetch and load the data and we need to run this twice a day as the data keeps changing, so need to be up-to-date with the latest data from the client.
4. There was a CPU maxing out issue as well but that has been resolved by keeping the MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount.

Question :

Is there a way to reduce the time taken by the process to complete.
Currently it takes 2 hours to complete but that could be due to no memory remaining as it reaches 4800 deals, and without any memory it cannot process any further.
Is there a way to reduce memory consumption here by trying out a different way to execute this or there is something if changed in the same code could make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Parallelism is most likely totally useless.  You are bound by the IO, not by the CPU.  The IO is the bottleneck and parallelization might even make it worse. You might experiment by using a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software) and then copy all the output to the actual storage.